# Do utility bill printers place envelope contents to the left of the envelope?

Tags: intelligent-design

After years of opening envelopes from bank statements to utility bills, I noticed that I tend to always tear off the right side of the envelope (I don't have a letter opener knife).

I've noticed that I've never managed to tear the contents of the envelope (maybe just once though, when I tore off more than 1.5cm)

Would I be right in saying that the machines that print and insert the contents so they "hug" the left inside edge of the envelopes are designed to do so on purpose?

*PS. This is the only relevant stackexchange site I could think of ask this question. Feel free to tell me to sod off to another!*

Comment: According to the [FAQ](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), Skeptics.SE is for researching the evidence behind the claims you *hear or read*. This question appears to be *your own* speculation, and is off-topic. Please edit it to reference a claim that other people are making and flag for moderator attention to re-open (or get 5 re-open votes).

Comment: @Oddthinking I did add a "PS". As moderator, would you care to direct me to the appropriate StackExchange site?

Comment: I am actually in a position where I could *ask*. Just not today; if I don't come back to this within a week, feel free to poke me about it.

Comment: ping @DevSolar !

Comment: OK... background, I am working for a company that (among other things) does printing and enveloping for advertising campaigns. (Me personally, I am working on software related to address management.) As far as I could find out, *there is no mechanism to make envelope contents "hug" a specific side*. Aside from adding complexity to an already complex machinery for no real benefit, the sorting and shipping done further down the line by the mail service would very likely upset whatever alignment the enveloping machine would do, anyway. -- Anecdotal "evidence", so a comment, not an answer.

Comment: [Topical if somewhat random YT link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NumvqYsAmKk&feature=youtu.be&t=56). ;-)